# Adding Plugins in QGIS Essen 2.14.0

Tags: qgis-plugins

I am still relatively new to QGIS and have been using it for the basemap image services associated with OpenLayers plugin_particularly, the Google Satellite service. I am now unable to add/see the All plugins option in the QGIS GUI.

I read the problems in the context of OL so I'm trying to access QuickMapServices but I'm not able to see any of the plugin options except those which have been installed in my previous version_now updated to Essen. Oddly, and pertinent to this question I think, is the fact that I downloaded the software on a new laptop and was able to access all plugins and see them successfully.

[image: AllPlugins not available]

Comment: Looks like a proxy/internet issue to me. If you have a proxy set it in Settings -> Options - Network

Comment: Can you advise as to which setting in the Network box I should edit?

Comment: @nmichelg - From the toolbar: _Settings > Options > Network_, there should be a tick box next to the option **Use proxy for web access**. Try unticking this.

Comment: Thankyou for this information. Looking at the proxy/internet options in the specific posts has cleared up my issue.   I appreciate the Community